# Load Spark Dataframe into ElasticSearch using PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Cannot simply load spark dataframe into elasticsearch as written here [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/master/spark.html#spark-python) (es is running on localhost). 
 What am I missing?

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("product_recommendation-server") \
                          .set('spark.jars', 'path/to/elasticsearch-hadoop-2.1.0.Beta2.jar') \
                          .set('spark.driver.memory', '2250m') \
                          .set('spark.sql.shuffle.partitions', '2000')


sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc)
sql_sc = SQLContext(sc)

spark_df = spark.read.csv(path, header=True)

spark_df.write.save(format="org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
```

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o77.save. :
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source:
>   org.elasticsearch.spark.sql. Please find packages at
>   http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html